# Basecamp API integration in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, basecamp

I need to implement Basecamp API for iphone app. I searched on google and got a Git hub link: https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api

It say that the API is rest based but I am not able to understand how to call this api. I also not able to figure out how to get Login using this API. This api contains .md files.

Please any one can help me how to call this API in iOS sdk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that - https://github.com/ScottPetit/BasecampKit. I didn't try it but it's only one realization  where you're not obliged to mess directly with basecamp api.

Some time ago I started to do some bascamp integration in my app but don't found any sinple solution
 and decided to make own basecamp ios sdk. I'll share it on github when it will be done.